# BSOD - "replacing invalid security ID with default security ID" - Cannot boot to windows, black screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, security, bsod

I was working away on my computer when it suddenly blue screened.  It's maybe done that once many months ago.  Upon Reboot it began running checkdisk, moving orphaned files and then it got to this line:

"Replacing Invalid Security ID with Default Security ID"

It proceeded to run this on 275k files -- it took about 4 hours.

Now when I attempt to boot to windows it says 'booting to windows' and then dumps me to a black screen in which the mouse cursor and a black desktop are the only things available.  No hotkeys respond and nothing else is visible, but you can move the mouse.  Does the exact same in safe mode.

I found a QA on microsofts website where the person had the same black screen result as me that suggested resetting all the file permissions to give everyone access and then resetting the default security settings:

I ran this command I had to modify because I had icacls instead of cacls:

> icacls E:\ /grant users:(f) /c /t

the command seemed to response, went to the next line, now i'm staring at it.  Anybody have any other suggestions on this?

Comment: In the moment I posted that, it started to respond after 10 minutes of doing nothing.  Moving pretty slowly...

Comment: That actually took about 45 minutes to run.  When it finished I was able to boot to windows.  Now there are corrupt messages everywhere.  Looks like I'll be salvaging what data I can and starting clean.